# Forward all traffic to a specific ipaddress in the network

Tags: php, configuration, routes, xampp, portforwarding

I am have a mini PHP websited hosted in a local-network of 5 systems. The 5 systems of connected are connected to a router.

```
192.168.0.1 -> router ip<br/>
192.168.0.11<br/>
192.168.0.12<br/>
192.168.0.13 -> PHP hosted here<br/>
192.168.0.14<br/>
192.168.0.15
```

How would I go about forwarding any traffic sent to the router to a specific IP address`(192.168.0.13)`? Even if I type `www.google.com` it should be forwarded to `192.168.0.13`. How can this be accomplished. Through some search I understand I must use a feature called Port forwarding. Is this right? And how do I configure it? A simple example would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You have to log in to router console. probably you have to type `192.168.0.1` in your browser and you will find in the menu `Port Forwarding` (or similar). Go there and add your internal ip `192.168.0.13` and the ports you will like to be forwarded. (80 for http for example).

The menu depends on the manufacture of the router so I can't tell you exactly.

Comment: I know its a very generic question. But will the console be available for every router? And how about the inbuilt wireless cards with ability of WiFi hotspots?

Comment: I don't know if it's available to every router. But for majority it is. Try it.